# OpenGL (lwjgl) Frame Buffer Object GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT Not Being Written To

Tags: opengl, deferred-rendering, frame-buffer, deferred-shading, multiple-render-targets

I am currently developing a deferred renderer for my game engine and I have to output multiple textures from my shader to my GBuffer.
I have been struggling with getting multiple outputs from the fragment shader. I am using OpenGL 3.3. My Frame Buffer class allows for multiple color buffers by binding multiple textures and receiving inputs from GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, etc... GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 works but using any different color attachment yields an empty texture. I have looked at many examples but cannot find what is wrong with my code. Any thoughts as to why this setup may not be working would be very helpful.

**Frame Buffer Creation Code:**

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL14.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;


import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class RenderPass {

private int framebufferID;
private int[] texIDs = new int[16];
private Texture[] tex = new Texture[16];
private int depthTextureID;
private int  colorTextureID;
private int depthRenderBufferID;
private int width;
private int height;

private Texture depth_texture;
private Texture color_texture;

private ArrayList<Integer> renderLayers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Integer> buffers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
IntBuffer drawBuffers;

public RenderPass(int width, int height){

    this(width, height, new ArrayList<Integer>());

}

public RenderPass(int width, int height, ArrayList<Integer> renderLayers){

    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.renderLayers = renderLayers;


    System.out.println("FBO is supported!!!");

    framebufferID = glGenFramebuffers();
    colorTextureID = glGenTextures();
    depthTextureID = glGenTextures();
    depthRenderBufferID = glGenRenderbuffers();     

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferID);
    framebufferID = glGenFramebuffers();                                         // create a new framebuffer
    //colorTextureID = glGenTextures();                                               // and a new texture used as a color buffer
    depthRenderBufferID = glGenRenderbuffers();                                  // And finally a new depthbuffer

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferID);                        // switch to the new framebuffer

 addTexture(0,false);

    // initialize depth renderbuffer
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferID);                // bind the depth renderbuffer
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height); // get the data space for it
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferID); // bind it to the renderbuffer

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTextureID);                                   // Bind the depthbuffer texture
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);               // make it linear filterd

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, (java.nio.ByteBuffer) null);  // Create the texture data
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE);


    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTextureID, 0); // attach it to the framebuffer

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);                                    // Swithch back to normal framebuffer rendering

}    
public void addTexture(int index, boolean isFloatingPoint){
    texIDs[index] = glGenTextures();
    if(!buffers.contains(index))buffers.add(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0+index);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferID);
    System.out.println(buffers);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texIDs[index]);   
      glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);               // make it linear filterd
       if(isFloatingPoint) glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, (java.nio.ByteBuffer) null);
       else glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_INT, (java.nio.ByteBuffer) null);  // Create the texture data
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
        glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0+index,GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIDs[index], 0); // attach it to the framebuffer

    drawBuffers = Util.createFlippedBuffer(Util.toIntArray(buffers.toArray(new Integer[buffers.size()])));

}

public void begin(){
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); 
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferID); 
    glDrawBuffers(drawBuffers);
    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        System.err.println("OOPS SOMETHING IS WRONG WITH YOUR FRAMEBUFFER");

    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);   

}

public void end(){
    color_texture = new Texture(colorTextureID);
    for(int i = 0; i<texIDs.length;i++){
        if(texIDs[i]!= 0)tex[i]= new Texture(texIDs[i]);
        //tex[i]= new Texture(texIDs[i]);
    }
    depth_texture = new Texture(depthTextureID);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  

}


public void addRenderLayer(int layerIndex){

    renderLayers.add(layerIndex);

}

public ArrayList<Integer> getRenderLayers() {
    return renderLayers;
}

public void setRenderLayers(ArrayList<Integer> renderLayers) {
    this.renderLayers = renderLayers;
}

public Texture[] getTextures(){
    return tex;
}
public Texture getDepthTexture(){
    return depth_texture;
}

public Texture getColor_texture() {
    return color_texture;
}

public void setColor_texture(Texture color_texture) {
    this.color_texture = color_texture;
}
```

}`

**Vertex Shader Code:**

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 vertColor;
layout (location = 4) in vec3 tangent;
layout (location = 5) in int materialIndex;

out vec2 texCoord0;
out vec3 normal0;
out mat3 tangentToWorld;
out vec3 worldPos0;
out vec3 vertColor0;
flat out int materialIndex0;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 transformProjected;

void main()
{   
    gl_Position = transformProjected * vec4(position, 1.0);
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
    normal0 = (transform * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
    //worldPos0 = (transform * vec4(position, 1)).xyz;
    vertColor0 = vertColor;
    materialIndex0 = materialIndex;
    vec3 binormal = cross(tangent,normal);
    mat3 tangentToWorld;
    tangentToWorld[0] = tangent;
    tangentToWorld[1] = binormal;
    tangentToWorld[2] = normal;
}
```

**Fragment Shader Code:**

```
#version 330

const int MAX_MATERIALS=16;

in vec2 texCoord0;
in vec3 normal0;
in vec3 worldPos0;
in vec3 vertColor0;
flat in int materialIndex0;
in mat3 tangentToWorld;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 colorSI;
layout (location = 1) out vec4 normalSE;
//layout (location = 2) out vec4 specularColorAO;
layout (location = 2) out vec4 EmissionAOMat;

uniform sampler2D Diffuse;
uniform sampler2D Normal;
uniform sampler2D Specular;
uniform sampler2D AO;
uniform sampler2D Emission;

void main()
{   
    colorSI = vec4(1,1,0,1);
    normalSE = vec4(1,0,1,1);

    vec4 diffuseTexture = texture2D(Diffuse, texCoord0.xy);
    if(diffuseTexture.xyz != vec3(0)){
    colorSI.xyz = vec3(diffuseTexture.xyz*vertColor0);
    }
    vec4 normalTexture = texture2D(Normal, texCoord0.xy);
    if(normalTexture.xyz != vec3(0)){
        normalSE.xyz = normalTexture.xyz*tangentToWorld;
    }
    vec4 specTexture = texture2D(Specular, texCoord0.xy);
    if(specTexture.xyz != vec3(0)){
        colorSI.a = specTexture.r;
        normalSE.a = specTexture.g;
    }
    vec4 AOTexture = texture2D(AO, texCoord0.xy);
    vec4 emissionTexture = texture2D(Emission, texCoord0.xy);

    EmissionAOMat = vec4(emissionTexture.r, AOTexture.r,materialIndex0,0);
    normalSE.a = 1;

}
```

**Mesh Draw Code:**

```
public void drawAdvanced(){

        //if(mat.getTexture() != null)
        //  mat.getTexture().bind();

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, Vertex.SIZE * 4, 0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, Vertex.SIZE * 4, 12);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, Vertex.SIZE * 4, 20);
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, Vertex.SIZE * 4, 32);
        glVertexAttribPointer(4, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, Vertex.SIZE * 4, 44);
        glVertexAttribPointer(5, 1, GL_INT, false, Vertex.SIZE * 4, 56);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(5);
        //if(mat.getTexture() != null)
        //  mat.getTexture().unbind();
    }
```

**GBuffer Code:**

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.EXTFramebufferObject.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL14.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.epicmstudios.openworldengine.core.FlatRenderer;
import com.epicmstudios.openworldengine.core.Mesh;
import com.epicmstudios.openworldengine.core.MeshRenderer;
import com.epicmstudios.openworldengine.core.RenderPass;
import com.epicmstudios.openworldengine.core.Texture;


public class GBuffer {

    private static RenderPass gBufferPass = new RenderPass(1280, 720);
    private static GBufferShader gBufferShader = GBufferShader.getInstance();

    public static RenderPass getGBufferPass() {
        return gBufferPass;
    }
    public static void setGBufferPass(RenderPass gBufferPass) {
        GBuffer.gBufferPass = gBufferPass;
    }

    public static void setUpTextures(){
        gBufferPass.addTexture(1, true);
        gBufferPass.addTexture(2, false);
        //for(int i = 2; i<4;i++)gBufferPass.addTexture(i, false);
    }

    public static void bind(Mesh mesh){
        gBufferPass.begin();
        gBufferShader.bind();
        gBufferShader.updateUniforms(mesh);
    }

    public static void unbind(){
        gBufferShader.unbind();
        gBufferPass.end();
    }

    public static void updateUniforms(Mesh mesh){
        gBufferShader.updateUniforms(mesh);
    }

    public static Texture getColorSI(){
        return gBufferPass.getTextures()[0];
    }
    public static Texture getNormalSE(){
        return gBufferPass.getTextures()[1];
    }
    public static Texture getEmissionAOMat(){
        return gBufferPass.getTextures()[2];
    }
    public static Texture[] getTextures(){
        return gBufferPass.getTextures();
    }

}
```

**GBuffer Shader Class Code**

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13.*;


import com.epicmstudios.openworldengine.core.Matrix4f;
import com.epicmstudios.openworldengine.core.Mesh;
import com.epicmstudios.openworldengine.core.ResourceGetter;
import com.epicmstudios.openworldengine.core.Shader;



public class GBufferShader extends Shader {

    public static final GBufferShader instance = new GBufferShader();

    public static GBufferShader getInstance(){

        return instance;

    }
    private GBufferShader() {
        super();

        addVertexShader(ResourceGetter.loadShader("GBuffer.vert"));
        addFragmentShader(ResourceGetter.loadShader("GBuffer.frag"));
        compileShader();
        //addUniform("transform");
        addUniform("transformProjected");
        addUniform("Diffuse");
        addUniform("Normal");
        addUniform("Specular");
        addUniform("AO");
        addUniform("Emission");
    }
    public void updateUniforms(Mesh mesh){

        //setUniformM4f("transform", mesh.getTransform().getTransformation());
        setUniformM4f("transformProjected", mesh.getTransform().getProjectedTransformation());
        setUniformi("Diffuse",0);
        setUniformi("Normal",1);
        setUniformi("Specular",2);
        setUniformi("AO",3);
        setUniformi("Emission",4);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        if(mesh.getDiffuseTexture()!=null)mesh.getDiffuseTexture().bind();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        if(mesh.getNormalTexture()!=null)mesh.getNormalTexture().bind();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
        if(mesh.getSpecularTexture()!=null)mesh.getSpecularTexture().bind();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
        if(mesh.getAOTexture()!=null)mesh.getAOTexture().bind();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
        if(mesh.getEmissionTexture()!=null)mesh.getEmissionTexture().bind();
    }
}
```